# Calculate the argument of $ (-2{\sqrt 3} - 2i)^5$

Tags: complex-numbers

So I'm supposed to calcualte the argument and the answer is supposed to be $\frac{11}{6}π$.

Instead of that I'm getting $\frac{5}{6}π$ because
$\frac{-2}{-2{\sqrt 3}} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3}} $ the argument of that being $\frac{π}{{6}}$ and when I multiply it by $5,$ I get $\frac{5}{6}π$

where is my mistake?

Comment: Notice that you are in the third quadrant.  If you were in the first quadrant, the answer would be $5\pi/6$.  But because you are in the third quadrant, just add $\pi$: $5\pi/6+\pi = 11\pi/6$.

Comment: More directly, the argument of $-2\sqrt{3}-2i$ is not $\pi/6$, it's actually $7\pi/6$,  and you can multiply that by 5 mod $2\pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$arg((-2-2\sqrt{3})^5) = arg((-1)^5)+arg((2+2\sqrt{3})^5)$$
$$=arg(-1)+arg((2+2\sqrt{3})^5)$$
$$=\pi+5arg(2+2\sqrt{3}) = \pi+5\pi/6 = 11\pi/6.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(-2\sqrt3-2i)^5=\left(4\left(-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\right)\right)^5=$$
$$=1024(\cos(210^{\circ}\cdot5)+i\sin(210^{\circ}\cdot5))=$$
$$=1024(\cos330^{\circ}+i\sin330^{\circ}),$$ which gives the answer:
$$330^{\circ}.$$